# GA - Track when visitor completes 2 actions

Tags: google-analytics

Looking to trigger/flag when a visitor completes 2 actions (visits an article page & also makes an enquiry). The 2 actions may occur within a session but not be consecutive. Whats the best way to set this up? ﻿

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en#multiple

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to this problem. Within the advanced segments we can setup a sequence to see when a visitor views a certain page followed by another page within the same session or over a period of time.